# Rounding off to nearest tenths

Tags: real-numbers, rounding-unit

Round off $0.2545$ to nearest tenths.
Following my instinct, the answer is $0.3$ because that's what it is more close to. Following the rules, as told by my teacher, it comes out to be $0.2$. Steps I followed while I rounded it as $0.2000$:

> 1. Last digit of $0.2545$ is $5$ and the preceding digit is $4$-even, so I write it as $0.254$
>
> 2.Now, in $0.254$, last non-zero digit is $4$ , so it gets converted to $0.25$
>
> 3.In $0.25$ last non-zero digit is $5$ and the digit preceding $5$ is $2$, even no. So, $0.25$ gets converted to $0.2$

Which is right answer?

Comment: You mean "thousanths."  Anyway, $0.2545$ gets rounded to $0.254$.  (The last $5$ could be rounded up or down, but the convention is to round to an even digit.... $4$.)

Comment: Opps my bad, I meant tenths!

Comment: Oh jeeeeezzzz....

Comment: that exception (if you are willing to follow it) tells you to round $0.25$ to $0.2$ but doesn't tell you to round $0.2545$ to $0.2$. https://www.e-education.psu.edu/egee102/node/1899

Comment: There's no need to successively round.  You're rounding to the nearest tenth, so you look at at the hundredths place (“first dropped digit”) and anything after it.

Answer (score 2):

To round to the "nearest" tenth, look at the hundredths place. If it is $5$ or more, round up. Otherwise, round down.

In this case, since we have $5$ hundredths, then it rounds up to $0.3.$

---

**Edit**: Based on your link, by Rule 2, we look at the hundredths, and seeing a $5,$ we round up, giving us $0.3$

Comment: But the rule says something else!

Comment: To what rule are you referring?

Comment: If the last digit is 5, then look at the preceding digit. If that is even, it remains the same, if that's odd, round it up by 1, in compensation of the 5 removed.

Comment: For one, I've never heard of that rule. For another, it is incomplete, as it doesn't tell you what to do if the last digit is **not** $5.$

Comment: There are other rules for when it is not. It is one of the rules on the list, you might take a look, https://www.e-education.psu.edu/egee102/node/1899

Comment: Your link agrees with my post. See my adjustment. The exception is new to me, but not applicable in this case, since the first digit dropped was $4,$ and not $5.$

Comment: This is the correct answer, despite OP's objections.